# Find all combination in group sorting

Tags: combinations, probability

I'm trying to find a code that will help me find all combinations in drawing groups.

I have 12 people to sort into 3 groups of 4. But I have some conditions: some people cannot end up in the same group as some others:

1 cannot be with 2, 3 with 4, 5 with 6, 7 with 8, 9 with 10. 11 and 12 can be with anyone.

I'm not trying to obtain the total number of possible combinations but all possibilities listed. I hope I'm being clear...

Any idea?

Comment: What language do you need?

Comment: Whatever language. To be fairly honest, I'm totally unable to code, all I can do is make some changes or add things in several languages. This is why I was asking for some code that would do what I need or be a base for me to bring some changes. At first I was heading for Python.

Comment: I don't think SO is the right place for this. If you need someone to write your code for you you could hire a programmer.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the help... I was just asking if someone could point out some existing code for me. I have my code for the groups, just need to find how to add my condition. Going to look somewhere else then. Bye!